# High probability bound for the The Double Dixie Cup Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, upper-lower-bounds, coupon-collector

The [Double Dixie Cup Problem](https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Double-dixie-cup-problem.pdf) is similar to the [Coupon collector's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) problem where a collector buys a random card out of $n$ at a time, but its goal is to collect $m$ copies of each card (the Coupon Collector is the special case of $m=1$).

In the above reference, Newman and Shepp bound the expected number of coupons the collector needs to buy before completing the $m$ sets and show that it is 
$$
n \log n + (m-1) n \log\log n + O(n).
$$

I'm looking for a high-probability bound $T(\delta)$  such that the number of required coupons $C_{n,m}$ satisfies:
$$
\Pr[C_{n,m} > T(\delta)] \le \delta.
$$

Any thoughts on how to derive this?

Comment: Both of your attempted links are broken.

Comment: You could likely get a loose but potentially useful bound via Chebyshev’s inequality if you can bound the variance of $C_{n,m}$. To get a tighter bound, you could prove that the random variable $C_{n,m}$ is either sub-Gaussian or sub-exponential, for example, by bounding it’s moment generating function, which would directly give your desired inequality by standard arguments.

Comment: @DavidK - sorry about that. Fixed now.

Comment: @cdipaolo- how'd you compute the variance for using Chebyshev's?

Comment: The number of copies of each card is distributed Binomially. You can use the Chernoff inequality to derive a bound on the number of cards needed so that a specific card will be collected at least $m$ times with probability $1-\delta/n$. Then union bound over all cards and you're done.